# How to use Stored procedure in Entity framework code first approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

Net core application. I have below SP created

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            var sp = @"create or replace procedure Duplicate_config(
                        sourcequoteid in int,
                        sourceconfig in varchar,
                        destinationquote in int,
                        flag inout varchar(10))
                        LANGUAGE plpgsql
                        as $$
                        begin
                        flag := 'Sucess';
                        --returning 'Sucess'into flag;
                        end $$;";
            migrationBuilder.Sql(sp);
        }
```

Now I want to call this SP in my code. Since this SP is not returning any dbset and returning just flag.

If I have dbset then I can call await context.MyDbSet.FromSqlRaw but I don not have any dbset which gets returned. Can someone help me to integrate this SP. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: This should be relatively straight forward, but can you show your db set, the class and whats in the actual call. 

Additionally, have you watched this through SQL Profiler and seen wahts going through?

Comment: How do you use `FromSqlRaw`? And could you pls check the database if it contains this stored procedure?